# Python upload file to smb

Tags: python, samba

I'm trying to upload a file to a smb url with a python script :

```
file_fh = open(filename, 'rb')
director = urllib.request.build_opener(SMBHandler)
fh = director.open('smb://usrname:pwd@fs.foo.xy/dir/dir2/test/fname.mov', data = file_fh)
# Reading from fh will only return an empty string
fh.close()
```

I have an error:

```
decode
    raise ProtocolError('Server does not support any of the pysmb dialects. Please email pysmb to add in support for your OS',
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error smb error: Server does not support any of the pysmb dialects. Please email pysmb to add in support for your OS
```

The server OS is a QNAP firmware. So my first question is: is there a list of supported OS somewhere? What's the email to pysmb? And is there another library to do what I want to do?